# Could REST API OPTIONS be used as the HATEOAS only request?

Tags: api, rest, http, request, http-options-method

As I've understood it, REST MUST use the HATEOAS constraint to be implemented properly. My understanding of HATEOAS is that basically every resource should share information about what communication options it has and how the consumer can use those options to achieve their end goal.

My question is if the HTTP OPTIONS method could be used as a way to navigate a REST API. Basically the response from an OPTIONS request would include the possible actions to take on a resource which would make it possible to consume the API without knowing the endpoints.

e.g.
An initial request to the API

```
HTTP OPTIONS /api
```

Could return all resources available for consumption and their relations. Like a massive tree to consume the API and all it has to offer. This idea doesn't neglect implementing HATEOAS on other responses as well, but the OPTIONS request would allow navigation without returning data that the consumer might not actually want to consume.

Is this a really bad idea? Or is it something that is commonly implemented. I'm currently attempting to  implement a REST API but I'm having a hard time understanding the benefit of HATEOAS if there is no way to navigate the API without actually requesting data that you might not necessarily need when consuming certain end points. And I assume HATEOAS aims to make clients consume resources by their relation and not actually hard coding the end point?

---

**TL;DR**

Could HTTP OPTIONS request act as a way to navigate a REST API by returning what communication options are available for the requested resource without actually returning the resource?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.7)

> The OPTIONS HTTP method requests information about the communication options available for the target resource, at either the origin server or an intervening intermediary. This method allows a client to determine the options and/or requirements associated with a resource, or the capabilities of a server, without implying a resource action.
>
> ...
>
> A server generating a successful response to OPTIONS SHOULD send any header fields that might indicate optional features implemented by the server and applicable to the target resource (e.g., Allow), including potential extensions not defined by this specification. The response payload, if any, might also describe the communication options in a machine or human-readable representation.  A standard format for such a representation is not defined by this specification, but might be defined by future extensions to HTTP.  A server MUST generate a Content-Length field with a value of "0" if no payload body is to be sent in the response.

So, basically a response to an OPTIONS request will tell your client which HTTP operations may be performed on a certain resource. It is furthermore admissible to target the whole server on utilizing `*` instead of a specific resource URI.

A response to an OPTIONS request may look like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Allow: OPTIONS, GET, HEAD, POST
Cache-Control: max-age=604800
Date: Thu, 13 Oct 2016 11:45:00 GMT
Expires: Thu, 20 Oct 2016 11:45:00 GMT
Server: EOS (lax004/2813)
x-ec-custom-error: 1
```

which states that a certain resource supports the mentioned operations in the `Allow` header of the resonse. Via the `Cache-Control` header a client knows that it by default can cache responses of safe requests (GET and HEAD) for up to 7 days (value is mentioned in seconds). The `x-ec-custom-error` header specifies a non-standard header that is specific to a particular software, in that particular case to a *ECS Server*. According to this [Q & A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22432379/x-ec-custom-error-1-what-does-it-mean) the meaning isn't publicly documented and therefore application specific.

In regards to returning a tree of traversable resources from the given resource the OPTIONS operation was requested for, technically this could be possible, however, certain systems might produce an almost never-ending list of URIs. Therefore such a design is questionable for larger systems.

> My understanding of HATEOAS is that basically every resource should share information about what communication options it has and how the consumer can use those options to achieve their end goal.

Hypertext as the engine of application state (HATEOAS) is basically just a requirement to use the interaction model used on the Web for decades quite successfully and offer the same functionality to applications. This enabled applications to *surf*  the Web similar like we humans do.

Great, but how does it work?

On the Web we use links and [Web forms](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html) all the time. Through a Web form a server is able to teach a client basically what properties a certain resource supports or expects. But that's not all! The same form also tells your client where to send the request to (target URI), the HTTP method to use and, usually implicitly given, the media type the payload needs to be serialized to upon sending the request to the server. This, in essence, makes out-of-band API documentation unnecessary as all the information a client needs to make a valid request is given by the server already.

On a typical Web site you might have a table of entries which offers the option to add new entries, update or delete existing ones. Usually such links are hidden behind fancy images, i.e. a dustbin for deleting an entry and a pencil for editing an existing entry or the like where the *image* represents an affordance. The [affordance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QIv9YR1bMwY&t=817) of certain elements make it clear what you should do with it or what's the purpose of that element. A button on a page wants to be pushed while a slider widget wants to be changed while a text field waits for user input. As applications aren't that eager to work on images a further concept is used instead. *Link relation names* exactly serve this purpose. I.e. if you have a pageable collection consisting of multiple page à 25 entries i.e. you might be familiar with a widget containing arrows to page through that collection. A link here should usually be *annotated* with link relation names such as `self`, `next`, `prev`, `first` or `last`. The purpose of such links is quite clear, some others like `prefetch`, that indicates that a resource can be loaded in the background early as it is very likely that the next action may request it, might be less intuitive at first. Such link relation names should be [standardized](https://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml) or at least follow the [Web Linking extension mechanism](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5988#section-4.2).

Through the help of link-relation names a client that knows to look for URIs annotated with `next` i.e. will still work if the server decides to change its URI scheme as it treats the URI rather opaque.

Of course, both client and server need to support the same media type that furthermore is able to represent such capabilities. Plain `application/json` is i.e. not able to provide such a support. [HAL JSON](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-kelly-json-hal-08) or [JSON Hyper-Schema](http://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/json-schema-hypermedia.html) at least add support for links and link relation names to JSON based documents, while [hal-forms](https://rwcbook.github.io/hal-forms/), [halo+json (halform)](http://halform.herokuapp.com/) and [ion](https://ionspec.org/#forms) might be used to teach a client how a request needs to be created. The question here shouldn't be which media type to support but how many different ones you want to support as the more media types your API is able to handle, the more likely it will be to interact with arbitrary clients not under your control.

These concepts allow you to basically use the controls given in the server response to "drive your workflow" forward. In essence, what you, as an API designer should do is to design the interactions of a client with your API so that it follows a certain, as Jim Webber termed it, [domain application protocol](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=7m00s) or [state machine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QIv9YR1bMwY&t=15m48s) as Asbjørn Ulsberg put it that basically guides a client through its task, i.e. ordering from your shop API.

So, in short, HATEOAS is comparable to Web surfing for applications by making use of named link relations and form-like media type representations that allow you to take actions solely on the response retrieved from a server directly instead of having to bake external knowledge stemming from some reference documentation page (Swagger, OpenAPI or the like) into your application.

---

> But how does HATEOAS benefit the consumer in practice then?

First, it does not have to consult any external documentation other maybe than the current media type specification, though usually support for well-known media types is already backed into popular frameworks or at least allows to add support through plugins or further libraries. Once the media type is understood and supported interactions with all serivces that also support the same media type is possible, regardless of their domain. This allows to reuse the same client implementation to interact with service A and service B out of the box. In an RPC-like systems you'd need to integrate the API of service A first and if you want to interact with service B also you need to integrate those API separately. It's most likely that these APIs are incompatible and thus don't allow the reusage of the same classes.

> Without knowing the URL for a resource, is the idea that the consumer can discover it by browsing the API, but they will still have a hard dependency on the actual URL? Or is HATEOAS purpose to leverage actions on a certain resource, i.e. the consumer knows the users end-point but he does not need to know the end-points for actions to take on the users resource cause those are provided by the API?

A client usually does not care about the URI itself, it cares about the content a URI may provide. Compare this to your typical browsing behavior. Do you prefer a meaningful text that summarizes that links content so you can decide whether to request that resource or do you prefer parsing and dissecting a URI to learn what it might do? Minifying or obfuscating URIs will do you no favor in the latter case though.

A further danger arise from URIs and resources that a client put meaning to. A slopy developer will interpret such URIs/resources and implement a tiny hack to interact with that service assuming the URI/resource will remain static. I.e. it is not unreasonable to consider a URI `/api/users/1` to return some user related data and based on the response format a tiny Java class is written that expects to receive a field for username and one for email i.e.. If the server now decides to add additional data or rename its fields, the client suddenly will not be able to interact with that service further. And rest assured that in practice, especially in the EDI domain, you will have to interact with clients that are not meant to interact with the Web or where programmers implemented their own JSON framework that can't coope with changing orders of elements or can't handle additional optional fields, even though the [spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259#section-2) contains notes on those issues. Fielding claimed that

> A REST API should never have “typed” resources that are significant to the client. Specification authors may use resource types for describing server implementation behind the interface, but those types must be irrelevant and invisible to the client. The only types that are significant to a client are the current representation’s media type and standardized relation names. [ditto] ([Source](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven))

Instead of [typed resources](http://soabits.blogspot.com/2012/04/restful-resources-are-not-typed.html) content type negotiation should be used to support interoperability of different stackholders in the network.

As such, the URI itself is just the identifier of a resource that is mainly used to learn where to send a request to. Through the help of meaningful link relation names a client should know that it is interested in i.e. `http:/www.acme.com/rel/orders` if it wants to send an order to the service and just looks up the URI that either is annotated with that Web Linking extension realtion name or that has an URI attached to it. Whether the link relation name is just an annotation (i.e. a further attribute on the URI element) or the URI being attached to the link-relation name (i.e. as an embedded object of the link relation name) is dependent on the actual media type. This way, if a server ever decides to change its URI scheme or move around resources, for whatever reason, the client will still be able to find the URI that way and it couldn't care less about the characters present in the URI or not. It just treats the URI as opaque thing. The nice thing here is, that a URI can be annotated with multiple link relation names simultaneously, which allows a server to "offer" that URI to clients that support different link-relation names. In the case of forms the URI to send the request to is probably contained in the [action attribute of the form element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#element-attrdef-form-action) or the like.

As you hopefully can see, with HATEOAS there is no need for a hard dependency on URIs, if so there may be a dependency on the link-relation name though. It still requires URIs to learn where to send the request to, but through looking up the URI via its accompanying link relation name you make the handling of URIs much more dynamic as it allows a server to change the URI anytime it wants to or has to.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying.

But how does HATEOAS benefit the consumer in practice then? Without knowing the URL for a resource, is the idea that the consumer can discover it by browsing the API, but they will still have a hard dependency on the actual URL?

Or is HATEOAS purpose to leverage actions on a certain resource, i.e. the consumer knows the users end-point but he does not need to know the end-points for actions to take on the users resource cause those are provided by the API?

Comment: @vkAndersson please see my updated answer. If something is still not clear, please ping back

Comment: How would consumption of such an API actually be achieved though? I understand that if I have a resource, say users, and the consumer know the endpoint /api/users he could achieve everything he intends on doing with and related to users through that endpoint without actually hardcoding the other endpoints. 

But what is the first step? Does he have to make a request to the root endpoint to start discovering my resources and instead of typing the endpoints the consumer will use the returned data.

Comment: Think of a web page. Usually you start at the root or the home and you find links from there. But you could also bookmark some page like /myorg/users and most webpages have a link (or multiple) that takes you to the home (or root) page from there. Same goes for APIs. The link relation `up` (which is registered with IANA) will take you to a "higher level/state" and is usually a good way to get to the home from any given resource.

Comment: @vkAndersson as sammygadd mentioned, this is similar to a typical Web page. Either you start from the entrance point of that API, i.e `https://api.acme.com` and progress your "way" through by looking up link relations and following the URIs attached to the link relation name or start by using a previously bookmarked link. Such a link though might get invalid over time

Comment: So correct me if I'm wrong.

The point of HATEOAS is not to enforce consumers to use reference variables instead of hard-coded endpoints? It's to discover the API, and OPTIONALLY use the actions/links etc to make some parts not rely on endpoints?

It's not for ease of development, it's for ease of discovery and understanding the API?

Comment: @vkAndersson the point of HATEOAS is simply speaking that you just use the controls given in the representation received to determine the next steps. The media type therefore is the ruleset that defines what a control is, how the syntax looks like and which other elements and attributes it supports. In REST you try to avoid coupling as, on the long run, this might prevent you from evolving your server or introduce interoperability issues later on. A REST architecture is intended for the next couple of decades, not just till the next technology arrives, as such evolution is a core principle.

Comment: @vkAndersson hard-coding endpoints into your client already bake in some knowledge of the API into the client and thus coupling. What if a server changes its URI structure, as it is free to do when ever it wants to? How should a client that has hard-coded endpoints coop with such a change? Thus, discovery is a future prove way to allow a client to coop with change. Building a RPC API is much easier compared to an API that respects all constraints of a REST API as it is not trivial to avoid any couplings (except to media types) at all, hence hardly any true REST APIs are yet out there